# ASP.net dataset

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dataset

```
da = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from revision_cycle_documenttype_mapping where project_id=" & Session("project_id"), con)
cb = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
ds = New DataSet
da.Fill(ds, "revision_cycle_documenttype_mapping")   <<--
mapping_count = ds.Tables("revision_cycle_documenttype_mapping").Rows.Count
Response.Write(mapping_count)
```

I am getting an error "Incorrect syntax near '=' ".
I have shown on which portion it's throwing error i.e da.fill.

Can you please help me?

Comment: I would assume that Session("project_id") is null or empty. You should be using command parameters instead of inline SQL to prevent possible SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

If it throws error on `da.Fill` then try to see the resulting SQL code first. Your `project_id` may be empty.

**Edit**

This is a possible solution

```
Dim projectId As Integer
If Session("project_id") IsNot Nothing AndAlso IsNumeric(Session("project_id")) Then
    projectId = Session("project_id")
    da = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from revision_cycle_documenttype_mapping where project_id=" & projectId, con)
    cb = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
    ds = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "revision_cycle_documenttype_mapping")   <<--
    mapping_count = ds.Tables("revision_cycle_documenttype_mapping").Rows.Count
    Response.Write(mapping_count)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your session `Session("project_id")` is empty, and this is not the best way to add a parameter in ur sql statement. your code here is vulnerable to sql injections.
you should first check if your session is empty and then you should add parameters by declaring a sqlcommand and assign parameters to it:

```
dim project_id as integer = 0
If Session("project_id") IsNot Nothing AndAlso IsNumeric(Session("project_id")) Then
project_id  = Session("project_id")
end if
dim cmd as new sqlcommand
cmd.parameters.add("@project_id",project_id)
```

the rest of your code would stay the same

Answer (score 0):

Use Parameters and check the null.

```
Dim projectid=0
If Not IsNothing(Session("project_id")) Then
   projectid=DirectCast(Session("project_id"),Integer)
End If

Dim sql="select * from revision_cycle_documenttype_mapping where project_id=@project_id"
dim cmd as new SqlCommand(sql,con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@project_id",projectid)

da = New SqlDataAdapter=(cmd)

cb = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
ds = New DataSet
da.Fill(ds, "revision_cycle_documenttype_mapping")
```